# View Model and Post action to Nested Classes in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been working on a mock website for a car dealership using MVC in .NET Framework. I am using razor pages to make a simple page to display existing models, and add a new model of car to the database, but no matter what syntax I use I can not seem to get my post data to properly map to the Model class when it is returned to my controller. Here is my VM:

```
    public class ModelVM
    {
        public List<Make> Makes { get; set; }
        public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
        public Model Model { get; set; }
    }
```

The list of makes is to populate a dropdown for adding. The list of models is used to populate a table of all Models. Here are the classes for each.

```
    public class Make
    {
        public int MakeId { get; set; }
        public string MakeName { get; set; }
        public string AddedByEmail { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public int ModelId { get; set; }
        public Make Make { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public string AddedByEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [Route("admin/Models")]
        public ActionResult Models()
        {
            var vm = new ModelVM();
            var _morepo = RepoFactory.GetModelRepo();
            var _marepo = RepoFactory.GetMakeRepo();
            
            vm.Makes = _marepo.GetMakes();
            vm.Models = _morepo.GetModels();
            vm.Model = new Model();
            vm.Model.Make = new Make();

            return View(vm);
        }

        public ActionResult AddModels(Model model)
        {
            var mrepo = RepoFactory.GetModelRepo();

            mrepo.AddModel(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Models", "Admin");
        }
```

Here is my page view. Everything works on it, except for the post function.

```
@model GuildCars.UI.Models.ModelVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Models";
}

<h2>Models</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddModels", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "row form-control" }))
    {
        <label class="form-label col-1" for="SpecialName">New Model:</label>
        <input class="col-3" id="ModelName" name="ModelName" type="text" required />
        <label class="form-label col-1" for="MakeId">Make:</label>
        <select id="@Model.Model.Make.MakeId" name="@Model.Model.Make.MakeId" class="col-4">
            @foreach (var m in Model.Makes)
            {
                <option value="@m.MakeId">@m.MakeName</option>
            }
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-1" type="submit">Save</button>
    }

    <div class="col-4">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Date Added</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var m in Model.Models)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@m.Make.MakeName</td>
                    <td>@m.ModelName</td>
                    <td>@m.DateAdded.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                    <td>@m.AddedByEmail</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

I have gone though 100 iterations of changing the name and Id, but none of them work. The MakeName is returned since it is a simple type, but the Make class within the model returns null. My goal is to get the Model being returned to the post controller to be populated with the Make selected in the dropdown. I have been programming for less than one year, so I am unsure if this is just a simple syntax error, or if there is a bigger concept that I am missing somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix an action input parameter, since your view uses ModelVm as a model, post action should use the same

```
public ActionResult AddModels(ModelVM model)
```

if you want to submit data you have to fix the view to use asp-for for the inplut controls

```
@{
var items=Model.Makes.Select( m=> new SelectListItem (m.MakeId.ToString(), m.MakeName) ).Tolist();
}
....

<input class="col-3" asp-for ="@Model.Model.ModelName"  type="text" required />
    <label class="form-label col-1" for="MakeId">Make:</label>
   <select asp-for="@Model.Model.Make.MakeId" asp-items="@items" class="col-4">
 </select>
```

to use this helper your Views Folder should contain _ViewImports.cshtml file with this code

```
@using TestCore.WebApp
@using TestCore.WebApp.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

but if you use old mvc you can replace view with this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Model.ModelName, new {   @class = "form-control", @required  = "required"} )

 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Model.Make.MakeId)
  
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Model.Make.MakeId, @items, "select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and IMHO you have to add MakeId to your model class, then your view model will be easier to understand

```
 public class Model
    {
        public int ModelId { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public string AddedByEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

         public int MakeId { get; set; }
         public virtual Make Make { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Serge, I plugged that in but it gives me a "SelectListItem does not have a constructor that takes two parameters" error. I had seen a solution that used something similar before, but ran into the same error when trying to implement it.

Comment: @jabroni51 You must be using a very old version of MVC. Check my updated answer.

Comment: ```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken=... />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
```

version 5.2 I think from my web.config.

I got rid of errors by removing the .ToList at the end, and adding a .ToString to the m.MakeId to get the page display without error, but now the Makes select does not populate options. dev tools:
```
<select asp-for="0" asp-items="System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[GuildCars.Models.Tables.Make,System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]" class="col-4">
```
instead of a populated select.

Comment: Anytime I see anything related to Core I get nervous that I am not supposed to use it, since the class I am in is for Framework. I know you can't speak for the requirements of my class, but in general would this be considered asp.net core functionality? When trying to add a .cshtml page with the using directories results in 'does not exist in current context' errors for all.

Comment: The new code block for the old mvc worked partially. The for the first time I can get the Id passed properly into the Model.make.makeId. Is it possible to adjust them to pass back the name into it from the dropdown as well? I can't thank you enough for the help to this point.

Comment: @jabroni51 As I  understand now you can get  Model.ModelName and  Model.Make.MakeId. What else do you need to post ?